# How to checkout 2 carts at once like Etsy does on Commerce 2.x?

Tags: 8, commerce

There are 2 stores, products from each store are added to cart, therefor there are two carts:

[image]

**But how to checkout these 2 carts at once:**

For example Etsy, clicking 'Proceed to checkout' will checkout the 2 carts at once.

[image]

maciej.zgadzaj's [Commerce Marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/maciej.zgadzaj/1950386) module introduced a concept of *order group* for Commerce 1.x, so that multiple order can be processed together.

http://zgadzaj.com/commerce-marketplace-installation-and-use-cases:

> Marketplace introduces concept of an order group (adding a property of the same name to the order object),so that it knows which multiple orders need to be processed together:

Is there any idea or suggestion to process multiple orders at once for Commerce 2.x?

Comment: You need to code a custom UI for that. And then hopefully release it as a module.

Comment: @BojanZivanovic So you agree with the idea of grouping carts with the concept of *order group*? I used the concept on commerce 1.x, added *order_group* property to order, it's complicated, I wonder there may be better solution on commerce 2.x.

Comment: Order groups don't really matter. In every solution you need to write a custom checkout-like form which modifies all of the orders at once. That's where all of the complexity is.