# Commerce multiple stores and multiple carts for B2B customers

Tags: 8, commerce

i have a problem with multiple stores.
i set up 2 stores of the same type. store **B2B** for B2B customers and store **B2C** for B2C.

all products are sold in store **B2B** and just a few also in store **B2C**.

when i add to cart products from **B2B** store, in cart page i have only one commerce_cart_form view.
when i add a product sold also in **B2C** store, i have 2 commerce_cart_form view.

the first one with products sold in **B2B** store and the second one with products sold in **B2C** store.

why are there 2 carts?

it seems that built multiple stores to manage B2B and B2C is not the right choice.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Commerce 2](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/setting-up-store/create-edit-store) documentation, stores are optimized for two use cases:

> We optimize for the two use cases:
>
> One business that has one or more locations or 2. The marketplace
>   model (where you have sellers)
>
> **One or more locations** This is the most common eCommerce situation where we have a single person, company, or organization that is taking
>   payments online.
>
> **Marketplace model** The marketplace model is where you have many sellers who are taking payment for unique products.

Each store can have a different currency, payment method, order flow, and so on.  So, each store also has a separate, unique cart.

It seems there are two ways to do what you want.

- Keep two different stores, one for **B2B** and one for **B2C**.  If the configuration is mostly the same, you will have to duplicate a lot of config between the two stores.  You will also need to keep the two stores separate so that B2B customers see the **B2B** store and B2C customers see the **B2C** store.
- Just have one store.  Add a select field to the products for admin to indicate whether it is a B2B product, B2C product, or both.  Then, modify the views that show the products so that B2B customers see B2B products and B2C customers see B2C products.  This way, you don't have to duplicate the config for the payment flow and so on.

Comment: thanks. i choose the second option.

so multiple stores can have only unique products and not shared one. if i sell shared product i will have 2 or more cart in the cart page.

if it is true, why in the product edit form, store setting selection has multiple options?

Comment: @FabioRiva Multiple stores can share products.  But, if you buy products from different stores at the same time, you will have multiple shopping carts.  You need a cart for Store 1 and a cart for Store 2.  If you don't want the products to be mixed, you need to filter the products so that users only see products for the correct store.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. you don't think that is a strange behavior? when i buy products from different sellers in amazon i have one cart.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 separate carts into 1 cart solution has not been developed.  Please refer to this discussion: [How to checkout 2 carts at once like Etsy does on Commerce 2.x?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242717/how-to-checkout-2-carts-at-once-like-etsy-does-on-commerce-2-x)